# Elasticsearch spaces to seperate words except for names

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, spaces

We are building a searchmachine with elasticsearch to use intern in our company.
We are using one inputfield where users can give in their searchwords (Google like). 
So it should be possible to search one different kind of words separate by spaces.

Everything is working great, but we have some problems with names…
If we search on “Tim Van De Velde”, there are no results for “Tim vandevelde” and this should be possible.
Keep in mind that we want to keep our spaces between the words to use our and-operator and that we do not want to many results that are not correct.

Any thoughts or idea’s how we could make this possible?

Take a look at our query:

```
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "most_fields",
            "query": "Tim Van De Velde",
            "operator": "and",
            "boost": 1,
            "fields": [
              "fullname",
              "alias",
              "name"
            ]
          }
        } ,
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "most_fields",
            "query": "Tim Van De Velde",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "fullname",
              "alias",
              "name"
            ],
            "boost": 0.8,
            "fuzziness": 1
          }
        }
```

Comment: could you post one sample document and mapping of fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you're looking for is a decomposition analyzer for compound names like the one you mention. Another approach is to use an `ngrams` analyzer which will take a sliding window of n-chars over your name. This approach gives you a good recall but somehow a worse precision. So I'd try with a decompound analyzer first and then `ngrams`.

The following plugin can handle compound words: [Analysis Decompound](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-decompound). It works without a dictionary. For a dictionary based approach use the [Compound Word Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html)

The name you mention will be split into following tokens when using the plugin [1](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-decompound):

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "tim",
      },
      {
         "token": "vandeveld",
      },
      {
         "token": "vand",
      },
      {
         "token": "veld",
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I searched around and I found https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html. But for some reason I can't get it to work.   Should it work with every word and language or only if your language is set to German?

Comment: It should work for all languages, btw. the plugin doesn't distinguish which language you process, the other language specific filters don't influence its behavior. Did you use the correct version of the plugin? It's picky when it comes to elasticsearch version compatibility.

Comment: the dictionary_decompounder is already included in elasticsearch, so I expect the version is ok :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to archive your goal: query pre-processing.

- Make a dictionay of person's names
- Receive input as “Tim Van De Velde” and return output as [ "Tim Van De Velde" or "TimVan De Velde" or "Tim VanDe Velde" or "Tim Van DeVelde" or "TimVanDe Velde" or "TimVan DeVelde" or "TimVanDeVelde" or "Tim Van DeVelde" or "Tim VanDeVelde" or "TimVanDeVelde" ]

Comment: Thanks, I think that should do the trick. Is it possible to provide an url where I can see how you can create a dictionary? Can't find much about it :)